# Scanner only picking up certain input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a Blackjack program using a Card and Deck class. Everything works except for one method in the main Class. Before every round of Blackjack, the player is asked if he would like to keep the same bet amount, change the bet, or exit the program (sentinel value of 0). The getBet() method is called at least twice(it could be called more than twice if this problem didn't stop the program). However, unlike the first time the method is called, the method only recognizes and acts on input of the sentinel. If you try and change the number or press enter, the player gets stuck in an endless loop on the console screen.

Why does the getBet() method, when called a second time, not return any input unless 0 is the value entered? All 3 classes are provided below. I would have provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, but, I thought the reader might prefer to run my actual code and, since the getBet() method seemed free of errors, I couldn't narrow down what the problem was.

**CARD CLASS**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card 
{
    private String suit, valueString;
    private int value, valueNum, suitNum;
    private final String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    private final int[] VALUES = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    private static int tot = 0;
    private static boolean[][] duplicateCheck = new boolean[4][13];//to see if suit/value pair has been used yet
    Random rand = new Random();

    public Card()
    {
        suit = createSuit();
        value = createValue();
        valueString = createValueString();

        tot += value;
    }
    private String createSuit()
    {
        String suit;

        do
        {
            suitNum = rand.nextInt((3 - 0) + 1) + 0;
            suit = SUITS[suitNum];
            valueNum = rand.nextInt((12 - 0) + 1) + 0;
        }
        while(duplicateCheck[suitNum][valueNum]);

        duplicateCheck[suitNum][valueNum] = true;

        return suit;
    }
    private int createValue()
    {
        int value;

        if(valueNum >= 9 && valueNum <= 11)
            value = 10;
        else if(valueNum == 12)
        {
            if(tot + 11 > 21)
                value = 1;
            else
                value = 11;
        }
        else
            value = VALUES[valueNum];

        return value;
    }
    private String createValueString()
    {
        String valueString;

        if(valueNum >= 9 && valueNum <= 11)
        {
            switch(valueNum)
            {
                case 9:
                    valueString = "Jack";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    valueString = "King";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    valueString = "Queen";
                    break;
                default:
                    valueString = Integer.toString(valueNum);//not really needed
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(valueNum == 12)
            valueString = "Ace";
        else
            valueString = Integer.toString(VALUES[valueNum]);

        return valueString;
    }
    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public String getValueString()
    {
        return valueString;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String str;

        str = valueString + " (" + suit + ")";

        return str;
    }
}
```

**DECK CLASS**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck
{
    ArrayList <Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int drawCard = 0;

    public Deck()//creates shufffled deck (each card is made at random)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 52; x++)
        {
            deck.add(new Card());
        }
    }
    public Card draw()
    {
        Card drawn;

        drawn = deck.get(drawCard);
        drawCard++;

        return drawn;
    }
}
```

**MAIN CLASS AND METHOD**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blackjack 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Deck newDeck;
        Card c = null;
        String name;
        int bal = 1000, currentBet = 25;
        char move = 'h';//hit by default
        int[] handValues = new int[2];
        ArrayList<Card> dealer = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Card> player = new ArrayList<>();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

        name = getName();
        System.out.println(name + " has $" + df.format(bal));
        currentBet = getBet(currentBet);

        while(currentBet != 0 && bal > 0)//determines when program ends
        {
            newDeck = new Deck();

            //player 2 cards, dealer 1 card
            firstDeal(c, newDeck, player, dealer, name, handValues, currentBet);
            System.out.println();
            move = nextMove();

            //loop: player hits until bust, stand, or hits 21
            while(handValues[0] != 21 && handValues[0] < 21 && move != 's')
            {
                System.out.println("\nBet: $" + df.format(currentBet));
                dealerStand(dealer, handValues);
                playerHit(c, newDeck, player, name, handValues);
                if(handValues[0] != 21 && handValues[0] < 21 && move != 's')
                    move = nextMove();
            }

            if(move == 's')//player stands
            {
                //loop: dealer hits until bust or stand
                while(handValues[1] < 17)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nBet: $" + df.format(currentBet));
                    dealerHit(c, newDeck, dealer, handValues);
                    playerStand(name, player, handValues);
                }

                if(handValues[1] >= 17 && handValues[1] <= 20 && 
                        handValues[1] > handValues[0])//dealer wins
                {
                    System.out.println("Dealer wins\n");
                    bal -= currentBet;
                }
                if(handValues[1] >= 17 && handValues[1] <= 20 && 
                        handValues[1] < handValues[0])//player wins
                {
                    System.out.println(name + " wins\n");
                    bal += currentBet;
                }
                if(handValues[1] > 21)//dealer bust, player wins
                {
                    System.out.println("Dealer bust\n");
                    bal += currentBet;
                }
                if(handValues[0] == handValues[1])//push
                    System.out.println("The game is a push\n");
            }
            else if(handValues[0] > 21)//player busts
            {
                System.out.println(name + " bust\n");
                bal -= currentBet;
            }
            else if(handValues[0] == 21)//player wins
            {
                System.out.println(name + " wins\n");
                bal += currentBet;
            }
            else if(handValues[0] == handValues[1])//both tie at 21
                System.out.println("The game is a push\n");

            System.out.println(name + " has $" + df.format(bal));
            currentBet = getBet(currentBet);//does stuff with 0, but not enter or new num
        }
    }
    public static String getName()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;

        System.out.print("Name? ");
        name = input.nextLine();

        return name;
    }
    public static int getBet(int currentBet)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp;

        System.out.print("Bet? (0 to quit, Enter to stay at $" + currentBet + ", or a new number to change bet) ");
        temp = input.nextLine();

        if(!temp.isEmpty())
            currentBet = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        return currentBet;
    }
    public static char nextMove()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String moveStr;
        char move;

        System.out.print("Move? (\"h\" for hit/\"s\" for stand) ");
        moveStr = input.nextLine();
        /*while(moveStr.charAt(0) != 'h' || moveStr.charAt(0) != 's')
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Enter either \"h\" or \"s\".");     //input validation
            moveStr = input.nextLine();
        }*/
        move = moveStr.charAt(0);

        return move;
    }
    public static int[] firstDeal(Card c, Deck newDeck, ArrayList player, 
            ArrayList dealer, String name, int[] handValues, int currentBet)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        System.out.println("\nBet: $" + df.format(currentBet));

        //dealer 1 card
        c = newDeck.draw();
        dealer.add(c);
        System.out.print("Dealer's hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < dealer.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(dealer.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        if(c.getValueString().equals("Ace"))
        {
            if(handValues[1] >= 11)
                handValues[1] += 1;
            else
                handValues[1] += 11;
        }
        else
            handValues[1] += c.getValue();
        System.out.print("Value: " + handValues[1] + "\n");

        //player 2 cards
        c = newDeck.draw();
        player.add(c);
        if(c.getValueString().equals("Ace"))
        {
            if(handValues[0] >= 11)
                handValues[0] += 1;
            else
                handValues[0] += 11;
        }
        else
            handValues[0] += c.getValue();
        c = newDeck.draw();
        player.add(c);
        if(c.getValueString().equals("Ace"))
        {
            if(handValues[0] >= 11)
                handValues[0] += 1;
            else
                handValues[0] += 11;
        }
        else
            handValues[0] += c.getValue();
        System.out.print(name + "'s hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < player.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(player.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Value: " + handValues[0] + "\n");

        return handValues;
    }
    public static int playerHit(Card c, Deck newDeck, ArrayList player, 
            String name, int[] handValues)
    {
        c = newDeck.draw();
        player.add(c);
        System.out.print(name + "'s hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < player.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(player.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        if(c.getValueString().equals("Ace"))
        {
            if(handValues[0] >= 11)
                handValues[0] += 1;
            else
                handValues[0] += 11;
        }
        else
            handValues[0] += c.getValue();
        System.out.println("Value: " + handValues[0] + "\n");

        return handValues[0];
    }
    public static void playerStand(String name, ArrayList player, 
            int[] handValues)
    {
        System.out.println(name + "'s hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < player.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(player.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Value: " + handValues[0] + "\n");
    }
    public static int[] dealerHit(Card c, Deck newDeck, ArrayList dealer, 
            int[] handValues)
    {
        c = newDeck.draw();
        dealer.add(c);
        System.out.print("Dealer's hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < dealer.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(dealer.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        if(c.getValueString().equals("Ace"))
        {
            if(handValues[1] >= 11)
                handValues[1] += 1;
            else
                handValues[1] += 11;
        }
        else
            handValues[1] += c.getValue();
        System.out.println("Value: " + handValues[1]);

        return handValues;
    }
    public static int[] dealerStand(ArrayList dealer, int[] handValues)
    {
        System.out.print("Dealers's hand: ");
        for(int cardNum = 0; cardNum < dealer.size(); cardNum++)
            System.out.print(dealer.get(cardNum) + "  ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Value: " + handValues[1]);

        return handValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the edit to my post, I couldn't provide a short, compile-able snippet of code demonstrating the problem because I couldn't narrow down what the problem was resulting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the Scanner!

I plugged this code into a debugger, and it gets stuck in an infinite loop in the Card.createSuit() function. The `duplicateCheck` dictionary gets filled with `true` so it can never pick the next suit.

Note: `duplicateCheck` is declared as static, so it will maintain its instance between "deals". `duplicateCheck` should probably not be inside the Card class, but in the Deck class instead, and NOT static. That way, each Deck instance will have a reference to which cards have been used. You can still call new Card() to generate a random card, but check the suit and value of the new Card instance inside the Deck instance.

Another note: this will still be a very busy deck generator since you are always generating a random card each time, which may be already part of the deck. I would recommend maybe having some Lists (or Sets) of "available" cards, and each time you want a card, you pick a random index in that List to get the card value/suit. Then remove that item from the List so that it is not available for the next card selection. I will leave that all up to you though. Have fun!

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Why does this problem only first manifest itself at the getBet() method? 2. How is this infinite loop an issue if only 52 cards are being created? There shouldn't be any extra cards to be created after the duplicateCheck array fills.

Comment: 1) It DOESN'T happen in the getBet method. It happens AFTER getBet returns, and the while loop has started again. This is where it builds a new Deck instance. However, since the reference to `duplicateCheck` it `static` it will be the same exact reference for the new Deck as it was for the original (first) Deck. THEREFORE: 2) The `duplicateCheck` arrays area ALREADY filled with `true` from the first Deck build. When the second Deck tries to build, it will continuously generate random cards, but finds that the card is "already in use" according to the `duplicateCheck` arrays.

Comment: So, the call to `new Card()` is causing the infinite loop as it tries to find a random card that hasn't been created for the Deck. Since `duplicateCheck` is already full of `true`, it will NEVER find an unused card => infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I believe I remember telling myself that I would need to clear the duplicateCheck array after each iteration, but I must have forgot. Also, after some further testing, I also came to the conclusion that it wasn't the getBet() method. I appreciate the help.